# Передать кириллицу в параметрах URL

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Коротко: Мне нужно передать кириллицу в качестве параметра URL. Google Chromе справляется с этим прекрасно, но богомерзкий IE почему-то отправляет его в другой кодировке.

Вот мой простой код, который это делает:

```
location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/cs105/livelink/Open/myreport?param=Параметр")
```

Я продебажил бекэнд и увидел, что, когда я вызываю этот код из хрома, в качестве значения param приходит русское слово "Параметр", но при отправке из IE10 прилетает слово "Параметр" в кодировке ISO-8859-1, т.е. в виде кракозябр.

Обычно, я мог бы сделать какой-нибудь EncodeURI и потом на бекенде преобразовать это обратно в кириллицу, но сейчас, в силу невожности редактирования кода на бекенде, я этого сделать не могу.

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ заставить IE нормально отправлять киррилицу в качестве URL-параметров?

Спасибо.

Comment: А если кириллицу преобразовать в %XX, где XX - 16-ричный код символа? Это вроде стандарт для URL, соотв. бекенд должен уметь её декодировать. То что хром отображает в адресной строке 'param=параметр' не значит что он так это и передаёт, пример (введите русское слово после '='): http://www.w3schools.com/tags/html_form_submit.asp?text=

Comment: Ну вот, к сожалению, не умеет. Т.е. конкретно тот хендлер, который обрабатывает мой запрос этого не делает. И я не могу на это повлиять. Моя логика такая - если хром как-то отправлять нормально, значит и IE можно как-то заставить.

Ок, а как проверить чего там хром и ИЕ передают, если не на бекенде?

Comment: Проблема не в том, что умеет, проблема в том что это стандарт, и никто не гарантирует что хром и завтра будет это уметь. И соответственно не факт что и IE можно заставить это делать, особенно учитывая что MS и к стандартам-то наплевательски относится.

Comment: Кстати, а вы проверяли что прилетает в бэкенд, если всё же закодировать URL?

Comment: @Alekcvp хром автоматически кодирует ссылки. Так что именно это автор и проверял.

Comment: @ifuwannaride Автор, `location.assign` - это javascript или что?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте URL-кодирование перед передачей на сервер. Хром это делает автоматически - и если с ним у вас все работает как надо - то достаточно закодировать ссылку правильно.

На чистом js это делается так:

```
location.assign(encodeURI("http://127.0.0.1/cs105/livelink/Open/myreport?param=Параметр"))
```

Но не все параметры так можно закодировать. К примеру, если в параметре будут не только русские символы - но и знак & - обработчик опять поймет вас неправильно. Поэтому лучше собирать ссылку из кусочков:

```
location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/cs105/livelink/Open/myreport?param=" + encodeURIComponent("Параметр"))
```

Ну а если вы используете еще и jquery - то можно воспользоваться функцией `$.param`, что куда более удобно при наличии нескольких параметров:

```
location.assign("http://127.0.0.1/cs105/livelink/Open/myreport?" + $.param({ param: "Параметр"}))
```